# Initialize Blazor scoped service using async method before components are initialized

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-5

I have a scoped service:

```
services.AddScoped<UserSettingsService>();
```

I want to call async method on the service (load data from DB) before child components are initialized (before `ComponentBase.OnInitialized();`)

Where is the best place to call `UserSettingsService.LoadAsync();`?

I have tried to do it in App component in OnInitializedAsync(), but it seems too late, because my childcomponents has been initialized before the UserSettingsService:

*app.razor.cs:*

```
public partial class App {
  [Inject] UserSettingsService UserSettingsService {get; set;}
  [Inject] AuthenticationStateService AuthenticationStateService {get; set;}
 
  public override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
     string userName = (await AuthenticationStateService.GetAuthenticationState()).User.Identity.Name;
     await UserSettingsService.LoadAsync(userName );
     await base.OnInitializedAsync();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not load user data in `UserSettingsService` constructor?

Comment: Put an `@if(someIsLoadedCondition) { }' around your subcomponents. Then they wont try and initialise until the loaded condition is met.

Comment: @BrianParker: It has a negative sideeffect. It will first render a blank page making a page refresh less eye pleasing. Additionally it breaks server prerendering, although I'm not using it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [`SetparametersAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.setparametersasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0) should do the trick.

The image is very clear about the blazor component lifecycle:
https://knowledgebasehavit.files.wordpress.com/2019/11/blazor-component-lifecycle-diagram.png